# Complex Oracle SQL search query optimisation

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, stored-procedures

Often a search in the database needs to be done based on some specified values. For this question consider that there is a table with a number of keys `K = {K1, K2 ... Km}` and a number of meta-columns `C = {C1, C2 ... Cn}`. Meta-columns are not included in any of the keys. What are elegant and efficient ways to perform a query where search criteria is defined as `S = {Ki, Cj1, Cj2 ... Cjh}` ?

Clarifications:

- Meta-column is any column that is not part of the key;
- S is a search criteria that contains always just one key and optional meta-columns to filter on;

Real-life example (story processing system):

- Key: time range, story_id
- Meta-columns: heading, reporter, editor, ...

Requirement is to be able to search on any of the keys with any number of optional filters supplied for meta-columns.

Possible solutions:

- One solution is to use Dynamic SQL. It's not preferred considering these [**reasons**](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/dynamisql.html).
- Use stored procedures, one procedure per key. Because only a subset of meta columns is specified expressions of type `table.column = NVL(paratemers.column, table.column)` for meta-columns can be used. I'm not sure exactly if Oracle would optimise that part of the query to avoid doing a comparison when `parameters.column` is `NULL` - that is part of the question. If yes, perhaps that is solution to the problem.

Are there any elegant solutions that wouldn't sacrifice performance?

Comment: hard to see what you are doing.  I think it depends on the density of the keys - if sparse, then an index on the key should be efficient.

Comment: Could you please give an example with a real-life layout? It's not obvious for me what is a meta-column or `S = {Ki, Cj1, Cj2 ... Cjh}` in this context.

Comment: Randy, apart from the keys there are other columns to filter on. How should an efficient query be written to filter on any number of optional non-key columns?

Comment: What is a "key" in your terms? Is it a composite `PRIMARY KEY`, or a set of independent `UNIQUE` fields? How is a time-range part of the key? It would be best if you just provided some data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL with bind variables is the way to go.  The "reasons" link you posted was correctly speaking against dynamic SQL with concatenated values - though its title does suggest it refers to all dynamic SQL.  In fact it goes on to show how to perform dynamic SQL using bind variables:

```
"SELECT * FROM SomeTable Where Field1 = @FirstValue AND SecondField = @SecondField"
```

Now, when some criteria (or "meta-columns" as you are calling them for some reason) are optional you can build the dynamic SQL based on the values that have been specified, and bind in the values when running it.

Comment: I've just read the linked article now. "Dynamic SQL needs to die" is a completely misleading title! If used properly with bind variables, then all the problems in the article are non-issues. And it's just written as a giant rant!